# Cygwin Screen Resume Fails Without Message

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen

I'm running some apps in screen under cygwin. However, when trying to reattach to the screen via 'screen -r', 'screen -x', and 'screen -RR' nothing appears to happen and I just get a new prompt line, no error messages or nothing.

'screen -ls' does list the screen as Detached.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is sometimes in the not-so-great terminal emulation of cygwin's terminal; All these problems went away for me once I switched to using the [fork of putty](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/) patched to connect to a local cygwin process like bash.

Comment: Thanks, this works a lot better on so many levels :) Copy/Pasting is less of a drag too.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to install mintty from within the Cygwin Setup.

You can select it in:

```
Select Packages > Shells > mintty
```

I've been using mintty ever since I found out about it.

Answer (score 1):

What terminal are you using?  I use [rxvt](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Rxvt) which works quite well.  The default terminal which runs inside a windows command prompt has many limitations.  Mintty is nice too, especially if you're used to Putty.